# How to know if my Silverlight app is running locally?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am developing a Silverlight 4 application and I want to enable/disable some features when deploying the app locally for testing purposes.

For example, metrics collecting will be disabled when I test the application locally to avoid spamming my database of "live" metrics.

The way that I am currently doing this is by checking the host name. For example, in my **App.xaml.cs** file:

```
if (HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Host == "localhost")
{
    // Do stuff only when deployed locally
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not enable the feature only in Debug mode (and not in Release) and deploy locally in Debug mode for testing purposes but otherwise in Release mode?

Comment: @GaussZ Except that I also often test my Release build locally before deploying it on my production server. Maybe I'm a bit paranoid :P
That's a valid suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: Never hurts to be paranoid. ;) But I fear there is no intrinsic difference except the Url, if you debug with a local IIS it might even contain your computername as host name and not localhost. The upside of a #if DEBUG precompiler switch would also be a slight improvement in speed depending on how many 'if's you run through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create two html pages to test my code, for example **mysilverlightpage.html** and **myslpage.notracking.html**. Then in the object embed tag for myslpage.notracking.html I add an initparam:

```
<param name="InitParams" value="noTracking=true" />
```

Then in my code, I do a check on my InitParams params:

```
if (!App.Current.Host.InitParams.ContainsKey("noTracking") || bool.Parse(App.Current.Host.InitParams["noTracking"]) == false)
{
    // perform tracking here
}
```

Now it's possible to check the release version for functionality without invalidating your tracking metrics.

Comment: Interesting, I think I'll give your idea a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to define your own Conditional Compilation symbol in the Build tab of your Silverlight project (eg: LOCAL) and then using the #if statement. Take out the symbol when you're ready to move your app. (Or do it the opposite way since you're actually disabling code)